# Are there any ETFs that follow the "Dogs of the Dow" allocation?

Tags: investing, etf, dividends

Essentially what it says on the tin. The ["Dogs of the Dow"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dogs_of_the_Dow) strategy seems to be a fairly popular basic strategy to follow for stock portfolio allocation - are there any ETFs that do this for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google is your friend. If you buy me a beer, I might be as well. By the way DOD is the ticker.

[Dogs of the Dow ETF](http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=DOD)

Comment: That is an ETN... Not an ETF. It's a derivative, when you own that ETN, you do not actually own any stock, and your investment has some (small) default risk.